# How to make a list with bullet to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have a this html code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipusm</li>
    <li>Lorem ipusm</li>
    <li>Lorem ipusm</li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
  position: relative;ń
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FF4237;
  top: 7px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/cjv/pen/jbONjZ)

and I want that list to look like this (red bullets in right side):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahRX9/3/)

I was looking for a solution but to no avail ;-(

Comment: The key to the second one is the `dir="rtl"` on the div, which is causing the browser to treat the content like a "right-to-left" text direction. Ex: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaOOam

Comment: You can set color of `ul` to `red` in jsfiddle demo:  `ul {color: red;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to this

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  direction: rtl;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "•";
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FF4237;
  top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `direction: rtl;` with your `ul`

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}

ul li:before {
    content: "•";
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FF4237;
    top: 7px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robinhuy/0y7h3dxn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in CSS

```
ul > li {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```